# Experiment to get all Wikipedia entry titles？

Tags: wikipedia

I am doing an experiment to get all Wikipedia titles. Check the website to find that Wikipedia has a total of 6.1 million articles, [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Statistics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Statistics) I tried to download all the titles using the method of other answers on [stackoverflow](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz), but there are 15,373496 titles under this .gz file. What is the reason? If I want to get the title of 6.1 million articles, is there any good way?

Comment: Let's us know how you have trying to solve that first to try to make easier to help you! Thanks!

Comment: Not really. What do you need that exact set of titles for?

Comment: (The difference is that the statistics exclude redirects and basically empty pages.)